# Не подгружается css

Tags: python, django

Файлы лежат в static/css/cal.css и static/scripts/cal.js,
css и js не запускаются,
network выдаёт 404

Settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
STATICFILES_DIR = [STATIC_DIR]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

head html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ru">
{% load static %}
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css\cal.css' %}">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>

</head>
```

При get запросе на http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/cal.css выдаёт page not found

Возможно это как-то влияет: при запуске пишет:`You have 13 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): auth, contenttypes, firstapp, sessions`. Но при py manage.py migrate выдаёт огромную ошибку

Comment: Какую ошибку то?

Comment: Заканчивается так, до этого 5к символов

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'name' in 'django_content_type'")

Comment: Может стоит закрыть ковычки в media_url

Comment: А, это я когда статью писал опечатался, тогда бы runserver вообще бы не работал